# Keep filter on table after table refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a table filter for my table. The table is reloaded with new results depending on what button you press.

What I'm trying to do is keep the filter on the table, after it's been reloaded.

Here is the table filter JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

    })

}(jQuery));

});`
```

Table Filter HTML:

```
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
<input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter by map or player...">
</div>
```

So each time a button is pressed, a div is reloaded with a php include for the table.

I'm guessing there would be some way to apply this filter after each button press, I'm not sure how though.

Comment: You might need Event Delegation

Comment: Please produce your issue in a Fiddle demo

Comment: @Manwal  I can't really do that as the table fetches mysql results.